# Snap.svg load external svg file doesn't show properly in Firefox

Tags: javascript, angular, svg, ember.js, snap.svg

I try to import old project written in Emberjs to new angular2 project. In emberjs my previous mate was loading external svg file like this:

```
<object id="svgobj" class="scaling-svg" data="/images/monitor.svg?v=3"
        type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

And then in JS

```
this.$('#svgobj')[0].addEventListener('load', function() {
      _snap = Snap("#svgobj");  
      self.registerCpuUsageControllerEvent();
      svgTooltip(_snap);
      self.go();
    });
```

I didn't like this way and I tried to load svg like this:

```
<div id="svgobj" class="scaling-svg"></div>
```

JS:

```
Snap.load("/images/monitor.svg", (loadedFragment => {
            $("#svgobj").append(loadedFragment.node);
            this._snap = new Snap("#svgobj svg");
            this.svgObj = true;
            this.start();
        }));
```

But now it doesn't work in Firefox.. Two screenshots below.

Chrome:
[image]

FireFox
[image]

So if I load it in old way, it works as in Chrome, If i use Snap.load it's broken.

Comment: does your html document contain a base tag?

Comment: @RobertLongson yes it's in head .. <base href="/">

Comment: remove that and the SVG should work.

Comment: Well, I need this base for my angular app :) App will not work without it.

Comment: You can't have it in your angular app. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8934

Comment: Thanks, seems like this is a problem.. Now I need to figure out how to safely remove Base tag.

Comment: By the way your title is misleading as you're no longer displaying an external svg file, it's now internal to the web page which is why it's affected by the html base tag.